# Wordpress - call wp_get_recent_post twice on one page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to call the wp_get_recent_post a second time on the same page.

Basically I need to call this code twice(with different categories).

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '4', 'category_name' => 'category', 'orderby' => 'date' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ):
              ....
        endforeach;
```

I read about `rewind_posts()` but I don't understand where to put it (as the examples in the docs are using other functions to get the posts data).
Could you explain the best way to deal with this?

Links to clear examples would be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: possible duplicated: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619411/using-wordpress-calling-a-function-twice-on-same-page-fails-second-time) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379962/calling-php-function-twice-only-works-once)..
finally please try using the **sleep()** function to pause for a second between two calls, i hope it works !

Comment: sorry but none of the 2 links you posted are about what I'm asking. wp_get_recent_posts is a specific function that goes around with the wp "loop" thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is; have you tried calling this twice? What happened?
That said I think you're going to need to add `wp_reset_postdata()` right after each  `endforeach;` to keep the rest of your page clean.

Comment: that's right, I was confused by another bug in my code that lead me to the wrong direction. Once that was fixed, this works.